# UI Labeling things for age at a glance

Tags: user-interface, user-experience

I have a web app for booking entertainers. I would like to see at a glance how long it's been since I booked them. Currently, I'm using colored labels.

- performers booked in the future : green
- performers booked recently :light blue
- performers booked long ago : dark blue
- performers booked never : black

Is there a typical way to label things that might be better than this? It's kinda weird. When I distribute this app, I want it to be immediately clear to the users that they are seeing a visual representation of how long ago the performer was booked.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I find there is a lot competing for the attention of the user, so maybe you can reduce the overall visual weight a bit.

Some things I'd look into:

- sorting the list according to the booking date
- grouping the list
- reducing the amount of different booking states to 2 or 3
- replace the tags by two different display styles: relevant to the user take up more space (future and recently booked) while the rest gets a collapsed view

Generally speaking it's better to improve a UI by leaving stuff out instead of adding more styles to fix a broken UI. What you choose depends on the priority of your use cases.

Not directly related to your question, the available button, the gray category tags and the bright booking tag are nearly unledgible due to a lack of contrast.

All the best with your app :)

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with previous poster that there is overall a lot of competition, I wanted to give you an idea for your question about the dates and labels:

Overall, using colored labels, you’ll have four different colour blocks competing —> tag, Edit, Availability, and this new Booking Status one. So instead, you could consider using an icon with your text instead and thereby do away with the colour.

I use FontAwesome codes (https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet?from=io) below for simplicity, but most icon sets should have a comparable one.

- Future: [fa-calendar-plus] *in 1 month*
- Recent: [fa-check-square] or [fa-clock] *2 days ago*
- Past: [fa-calendar-check] *02/2018*
- Performers Booked Never doesn’t need a label, since it’s the only exception and doesn't involve any form of booking.

On a side note:
- Perhaps consider reducing the number of hearts / blocks you have on each line, or using one heart with varying fills perhaps. I think it might be your primary culprit for the “clutter”.